# Top command display vertically

Tags: linux-kernel, command

I'm trying to use the top command to get only the CPU usage without all the non-needed stuff for this case. All I need is to get it shows vertically.

I've been searching on the internet for weeks, not finding anything since I'm not that great with Linux commands.

So the command I use (found on the internet) is this one:

```
top -b -n 1 | grep -i "^%cpu"
```

which gets me this output:

```
%Cpu(s):  0.2 us,  0.1 sy,  0.0 ni, 99.4 id,  0.3 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
```

Question is, is there a way to get all of this vertically?

i.e.

```
%Cpu(s):
0.2 us,
0.1 sy,
0.0 ni,
99.4 id,
0.3 wa,
0.0 hi,
0.0 si,
0.0 st
```

Comment: Sorry i cant even get to show it vertically here :D

Comment: Like after every "," theres a new line

Comment: Fixed that @Davide.

Comment: @JackBashford thank you so much THAT'S EXACTLY what i'm looking for

Comment: Tip for you: If you want to have a single line break (e.g. newline with no blank line), just add two spaces at the end of the line, then press enter/return once, then add your next line.

Comment: @JackBashford thanks a lot I'll do better next time I promise, i'm trying to reach that 90% questioning ;)